# reloadData after moveRowAtIndexPath

Tags: swift, checkbox, tableview, reloaddata

I have one `tableview` with two sections: ingredients to buy and ingredients that user has already. So, basically when uses does shopping he/she passes one ingredient from one list to another.

Here is `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("IngredientCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! IngredientCell
   cell.checkbox.checkboxDelegate = self
   cell.checkbox.checkboxIndex = indexPath
   ...
}
```

I will call this one:
(I included stateOfCheckbox - every tableviewcell includes a custom button with a role of a `checkbox` - basically this one gives me the direction from/to I will do the move).

```
 func doChange(stateOfCheckbox: Bool, row: Int){
   let fromSection = stateOfCheckbox ? 0 : 1
   let toSection = stateOfCheckbox ? 1 : 0

   let fromIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: row, inSection: fromSection)
   let toIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: toSection)

   let dataPiece = ingredients[fromIndexPath.section][fromIndexPath.row]
   ingredients[toIndexPath.section].insert(dataPiece, atIndex: toIndexPath.row)
   ingredients[fromIndexPath.section].removeAtIndex(fromIndexPath.row)

   ingredientsTableView.moveRowAtIndexPath(fromIndexPath, toIndexPath: toIndexPath)
   ingredientsTableView.reloadData()
}
```

I wouldn't want to call `reloadData`, but when not called somehow table indexes got mixed up. Is it necessary? Or there is another way?

This is how is behaves if `reloadData` is not present. I don't want to reload everything and repaint again. What would be a best practice?

[image: behaviour]

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "indexes got mixed up"? What happens, do you get an error?

Comment: At first when a checkbox is selected, the row will be send to the second section. The second time, if I select the third row, it could send the fourth ingredient to 'Got'em' section. And the checkbox remains selected for the third. (I don't have checked items in first section). It just seems that the painting is not done correctly.

Comment: Your `row` seems to be off by one. Could you post some of the code where `doChange()` is called?

Comment: I can post. But everything goes ok when `reloadData` is called, and not always the second disappears, it could disappear the third sometimes.

Comment: `if let delegate = checkboxDelegate, let index = checkboxIndex{
        delegate.doChange(isChecked, row: index)
      }`                The checkboxIndex is set in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath with indexPath.row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the problem is not in the code you posted in your question. From what I'm seeing in the Gif, the following must be the case:

If you check one, and afterwards check one below that, the index is shifted by one. What's actually going on: It still uses the old index from before the first one was checked. These indices will either need to be refreshed or - what I would prefer - determined when you're actually tapping it.

Comment: Oh, I think I get it. I'm doing this (in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`) `cell.checkbox.checkboxIndex = indexPath `, and I am using it later in `doChange` method. When not calling `reloadData`, new indices don't get computed. I will try out. Thank you for enlightenment!

Answer (score 0):

You can use UITableView's method : **tableview.beginUpdates()** and **tableview.endUpdates()**

```
func doChange(stateOfCheckbox: Bool, row: Int){
   let fromSection = stateOfCheckbox ? 0 : 1
   let toSection = stateOfCheckbox ? 1 : 0

   let fromIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: row, inSection: fromSection)
   let toIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: toSection)

   let dataPiece = ingredients[fromIndexPath.section][fromIndexPath.row]
   ingredients[toIndexPath.section].insert(dataPiece, atIndex: toIndexPath.row)
   ingredients[fromIndexPath.section].removeAtIndex(fromIndexPath.row)

   tableview.beginUpdates()
   ingredientsTableView.moveRowAtIndexPath(fromIndexPath, toIndexPath: toIndexPath)
   tableview.endUpdates()

}
```

Comment: I've tried out your solution without success. The behaviour is still present. I've done a gif to illustrate this. When I `reloadData`, everything is ok, although I can see a flickr.